# How to get all documents on specific day

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all Firestore documents from yesterday. All my docs have timestamp field.

How I can query for all documents from a specific day?

For example:

```
 const yesterdayDocs = await admin.firestore().collection('coll')
     .where('timestamp', '==', yesterday)
     .get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use inequalities - less than today, more than two days ago.  The timestamps are on a microsecond level, and are not stored in a parsed form to compare hours, days, weeks or such like.  Firebase does have functions to generate timestamp values (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp), and you can then use those for the less than and greater than clauses. something like

```
collectionRef
.where('timestamp', '<', TODAY_STARTED_AT)
.where('timestamp', '>', YESTERDAY_STARTED_AT)
.get();
```